# Crystal Reports in VS2010: How do I get an integer value?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I've got a value coming into my Crystal Report. I need to print it in the format:

"*" & myNumber & "*"

I just can't seem to be able to tell it that the number I want is an integer.

So I end up with something equivalent to this:

"*" & myNumber & ".00*"

I don't want those decimal values there. I just want an asterisk, the integer value of my number, and another asterisk.

How can I get that to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with a formula `"*" + ToText({table.field}, 0) + "*"` or simply insert the field into a text box, right click that field, and set the decimal precision from the number tab.

Comment: Thank you. The formula was the solution. I couldn't set the decimal precision because it's already a formula (because I have to add the asterisks), and I've been going mad for the last hour and a half trying to work out how to get an integer value in a system that only has a "Number" type. >_<

Comment: @Frosy840 yes, you will go mad if you work with Crystal long enough! For the second way with the text box, you can add the asterisks to the text box then drag a numeric field directly inside the textbox and change that field's display properties via the context menu.